# Reverse mysql_fetch_array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, while-loop, fetch

```
mysql_select_db("grozavco_gallery", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Images");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo '<div class="thumb" id="' . $row['ID'] . '"><a class="ajax" href="gallery/' . $row['ID'] . '.html">';
  echo '<p class="work-type">' . strtoupper ($row['Category']) . '</p>';
  echo '<img src="http://grozav.com/images/thumbs/' . $row['ID'] . '-bwthumb.jpg" alt=""/>';
  echo '<img src="http://grozav.com/images/thumbs/' . $row['ID'] . '-thumb.jpg" alt="" class="color"/>';
  echo '</a></div>'; 
  }
```

I want this to display in a reversed order. Can someone tell me how to do it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: A general recommendation: Instead of using `SELECT *`, use `SELECT ID, Category`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about simply change `ORDER` in query ?

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Images ORDER BY ID DESC");
```

You can also grab all data to some array before printing and then do `array_reverse` on it.